# Attach an object as modified in RIA service

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a client silverlight application that use RIA service to connect to database
Instead of `EntitySet` to manage entities I have a local cache of data that contain a list of all loaded entities and my context is always empty, this allow me to create multiple queries with multiple logical views into same database table and a better refresh(support remove and handle server triggers for changes).

Now my problem is when an entity change and I want to attach it to `EntitySet` and submit those changes to the server, `Attach` function attach object as `unmodified`.

So my question is **how can I attach an entity as `modified` in the client side of a RIA service**. I know how to do it in the server side but I need to do it in the silverlight

Comment: Why don´t you attach the entity first and then make your modifications? That should change the entity to Modified

Answer (score 0):

From the context - use the .Attach - method.  This will "attach" an entity back to a context allowing the context to track changes to the entity.  When you issue a save command, the context execute the appropriate command to CRUD the entity on the server.

Try attaching the entity first, then setting the EntityState as Modified.

Yes - I should have read the whole question before answering! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in silverlight EntityState in a read only property

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422332%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) interface of the Entity class to solve your problem. The interface is implemented explicitly on Entity, so you have to cast the instance to the interface.

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
MyEntitySet.Attach(entity);

((IEditableObject)entity).BeginEdit();
// edit the properties of the entity;
((IEditableObject)entity).EndEdit();
```